# Dropped column in multicolumn table

Tags: tables, multicolumn

In a table with 4 rows and 4 columns I try to merge different cells in every row while preserving the table layout. As there are never more than 3 cells in a row, a table column seems to be dropped.

If I add an empty row containing 4 cells there are 4 columns. Question: is it possible to preserve all columns without adding an empty row? Thank you.

Here is my goal:

```
-------------------
| 1               |
-------------------
| 2          | 14 |
-------------------
| 3 | 7      | 15 |
-------------------
| 4 | 8 | 12      |
-------------------
```

And here, what I get:

```
 --------------
| 1          |
--------------
| 2     | 14 |
--------------
| 3 | 7 | 15 |
--------------
| 4 | 8 | 12 |
--------------
```

The code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}

\section{A}
{\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
  \hline \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{1} \\
  \hline \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{2} & 14 \\
  \hline 3 & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{7} & 15 \\
  \hline 4 & 8 & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{12} \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}}

\section{B}
{\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
  \hline \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{1} \\
  \hline \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{2} & 14 \\
  \hline &   &   &   \\
  \hline 3 & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{7} & 15 \\
  \hline 4 & 8 & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{12} \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}}

\section{Goal}

I would like to have a table as in section B but without the third (empty) row.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is probably what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\section{A}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
  \hline \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{1} \\
  \hline \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{2} & 14 \\
  \hline 3 & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{7} & 15 \\
  \hline 4 & 8 & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{12} \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\section{B}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
  & & \phantom{12} & \\[-\normalbaselineskip] % fake/empty row
  \hline \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{1} \\
  \hline \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{2} & 14 \\
  \hline 3 & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{7} & 15 \\
  \hline 4 & 8 & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{12} \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\section{Goal}

I would like to have a table as in section B but without the third (empty) row.

\end{document}​
```

The motivation behind this solution stems from what is commonly used in the `tabbing` environment where you specify the tabbing intervals and then `\kill` the row.

Note that you don't need [`multicol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol) for this, since the default `tabular` is supported in LaTeX.

Comment: thanks for the multicol package remark! I like the fake row approach (because I must generate the table), will try out tomorrow. - I'm almost perplexed how fast and good in quality these tex.stackexchange answers are. Many thanks to all of you!

Comment: there were vertical lines (in table 2B), I used the following line to get rid of them:`code`\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}\\[-\normalbaselineskip]`code`

Answer (score 2):

It's a feature of the underlying `\halign` primitive that any column boundary that is spanned in every row is removed from the column width calculation.

Perhaps the easiest thing is to change the first line to

```
  \hline \multicolumn{2}{|l}{1}&\multicolumn{1}{l}{} &\
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to have a 4 column table, but only have 3 columns of data. If you know the width of the additional column you want, you can add that as `\hphantom{14}` (assuming that the width of the other column is equivalent to the width of the digits `14`:

[image]

### Note:

- The additional `\hspace*{\tabcolsep}` is required to take into account the separation that is added in between column tables.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}

\section{A}
{\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
  \hline \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{1} \\
  \hline \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{2} & 14 \\
  \hline 3 & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{7} & 15 \\
  \hline 4 & 8 & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{12} \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}}

\section{B}
{\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
  \hline \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{1} \\
  \hline \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{2} & 14 \\
  \hline &   &   &   \\
  \hline 3 & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{7} & 15 \\
  \hline 4 & 8 & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{12} \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}}

\section{Goal}

I would like to have a table as in section B but without the third (empty) row.

\section{C}
{\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
  \hline \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{1} \\
%  \hline 1 & & & \\
  \hline \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{2} & 14 \\
  \hline 3 & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{7\hspace*{\tabcolsep}\hphantom{14}} & 15 \\
  \hline 4 & 8 & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{12}  \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}}





\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. With the key `hvlines`, all the rules are drawn excepted in the blocks (created by `\Block`).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{llll}[hvlines]
   \Block{1-4}{} 1 \\
   \Block{1-3}{} 2 &&& 14 \\
   3 & \Block{1-2}{} 7 && 15 \\
   4 & 8 & \Block{1-2}{} 12 \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]